# Linear gradients in SVG without defs

Tags: svg, gradient, linear-gradients

I can use linear gradient in SVG with defs-section like:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="myLinearGradient1"
                    x1="0%" y1="0%"
                    x2="0%" y2="100%"
                    spreadMethod="pad">
      <stop offset="0%"   stop-color="#00cc00" stop-opacity="1"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#006600" stop-opacity="1"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"
     style="fill:url(#myLinearGradient1)" />

</svg>
```

Can I use linear gradient without defs-section?  I find something like this:

```
<rect style="fill:lineargradient(foo)">
```

Comment: I'm also trying to define gradients in pure CSS without having to define it in every single SVG file. Most importantly without an `id` tag because when the SVG appears multiple times on a page (e.g. an icon) the clashing ids are not unique and it's not valid HTML. So far I have not found a solution...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<defs>` is only needed for structuring purposes, the elements in it are not displayed, but since a gradient can only be visible when applied to a shape or another element, you can define it in any place of the document.

But you still have to stick to the correct syntax:

```
<rect style="fill:url(#myLinearGradient1)" ... />
```

Comment: This answer does not answer the question. Is it possible or is it not possible to use gradients without defining them in the defs tags.

Comment: @func0der spacially fo you, the answer can be read as "Yes, because..."

Comment: It does not work though. At least not for me. Using the style attribute and css "linear-gradient" gives me nothing. Therefore it would be great, if you could add a working example to your answer, because your answer states that it works, like suggested from the OP.

Comment: @func0der the question is about SVG `<linearGradient>`, not CSS `linear-gradient(...)`, and example is in the question itself.

Comment: There is no "lineargradient" svg function. And as you see in the example you are talking about, he uses the "style" attribute which makes it a css "linear-gradient". Point is: It is not working

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can indeed have a gradient without needing to have a defs element; you simply put the gradient element anywhere else in the code instead, for example like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

  <linearGradient id="myLinearGradient1"
                x1="0%" y1="0%"
                x2="0%" y2="100%"
                spreadMethod="pad">
    <stop offset="0%"   stop-color="#00cc00" stop-opacity="1"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#006600" stop-opacity="1"/>
  </linearGradient>

  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"
     style="fill:url(#myLinearGradient1)" />

</svg>
```

Comment: Although your example doesn't have <defs> around the linearGradient element it really doesn't answer the question. The goal is to be able to define gradients in CSS without having to define it in every single SVG file. Also one of the biggest problems is that if you use an SVG multiple times on a page (e.g. an icon) having the same `id` appear multiple times is not valid HTML.